# What is the location of project directory on openshift?

Tags: openshift, remote-access, remote-server, openshift-client-tools

I connected to an php application on openshift with winscp but I can not find folder with index.php.

Does anyone have any idea where it is located??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check `app-root/runtime/repo/` and directories inside it. I do not use php, but my python app is in `app-root/runtime/repo/wsgi/app-name/`.

Answer (score 0):

You must read [Global variables in openshift](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html)

OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR
The home directory of the application.

If you want to access from an specific programming language, I could improve my answer.